# Passing GET Variables as a /param/ in MVC PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, get

I am currently learning MVC PHP, and have a dropdown menu on my `localhost/dashboard/index` page (where `dashboard` is the controller and `index` is the method).

I understand how to, and have set up my `.htaccess` to treat additional URL parameters as GET variables, but how do I send form data *to* those parameters? Let me explain.

A simple dropdown on my page:

```
<form action="<?=URL?>dashboard/index" method="get">
    <select name="ID" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">ID #1</option>
        <option value="2">ID #2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

On submission, this takes me to `localhost/dashboard/index/?ID=1`, but shouldn't I be writing my URL like `localhost/dashboard/index/1`?

I can work with that GET within my controller and model no problem, but for conforming to standards, shouldn't it be using the `controller/method/param/` format?

Comment: This is not how rewriting works. Rewriting can only modify _incoming_ requests. It does not affect the browsers behavior. For that you have to make the requests by means of a client side logic (read: "javascript") instead of relying on the standard html form behavior. So it is up to you to actually send the requests to the desired URL. There is no magic that does this for you...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do this? Should I instead POST the data to a separate method, which then reformats the form data and redirects me back to the same page, parameters intact?

Comment: As said above: you use javascript (so client side logic) to submit he form, so to make the request. There are many examples for that to be found. It is pretty standard these days.